# Continue Through An If Statement If False

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm trying to create a simple ignore list option for my program. When a sub runs, I want it to not execute some code if a user is on the list and a checkbox is checked.

I have tried this:

```
If Not My.Settings.IgnoredNames.Contains(PartnerDisplayName) AndAlso chkIgnore.Checked = False) Then
    'Do something...
End If
```

This works, except even when the check box is checked by itself the if statement doesn't continue. I don't have a clue how to rewrite it.

This will not work either and I don't really know why. The sub triggers on an certain API event, and exiting it like so still lets the real code go through.

```
If My.Settings.IgnoredNames.Contains(ParterDisplayName) And chkIgnore.Checked = True Then Exit Sub
'Do something...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Nots` and creating messy logic, just invert your `If` statement and short circuit out if you hit the condition where you don't want to run the code:

```
If My.Settings.IgnoredNames.Contains(PartnerDisplayName) AndAlso chkIgnore.Checked = True Then
    Return
End If
' Do your other logic here.
```